# Azure Functions service not recognizing request sent from outside client

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a service which pings our EP1 Premium service and yesterday we received 3 client side timeout errors after 2 minutes of waiting. When opening the trace in App insights, these requests which time out are not even logged and have no trace of ever being received Azure side, and therefore stay unanswered. By looking at the metrics provided in the Azure Functions app, I found out that 1-2 minutes after the request has been sent, the app loses all its ability to work as its Total App Domains falls to 0 as well as all connections, threads and so on and this state lasts until the next request is received, therefore "skipping" the request that happened beforehand. This is a big issue as I need to make sure requests get answered in a timely manner.

The client service sent HTTP requests to the Azure Functions app expecting an answer, only to time out while the Azure-side doesn't have any record of ever receiving the request.

Comment: is the app which originates the request is also running on Azure?

Comment: What is the tier of the Azure Function ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issues is related to **Consumption Plan** of Azure Functions called `Cold Start behaviour`. The "skipping" mechanism is explained below:

> Apps may scale to zero when idle, meaning some requests may have additional latency at startup. The consumption plan does have some optimizations to help decrease cold start time, including pulling from pre-warmed placeholder functions that already have the function host and language processes running.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#cold-start-behavior

Please also consider of having look on this article, which explains the behaviour. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/